# Batch file web login via user on htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, batch-file, authentication, ftp

I'm having a problem with a simples task, I need a .BAT file that opens my firefox and login via user/pass on htaccess.

To open the website:

```
start firefox https://www.mywebsite.com/restricted
```

But to login would be something like this?

```
start firefox user|pass@https://www.mywebsite.com/restricted
```

But this doesn't work...

So, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll rather need selenium or similar automation plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to include user and password in the link:

```
https://user:pass@www.mywebsite.com/restricted
```

Comment: On more thing. The website ask for a confirmation. I've tried to include that with an ENTER command, but it's not workin. Could you take a look please?

`start firefox https://user:pass@www.mywebsite.com/restricted


set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()`

Comment: Oh it's ok. You helped me a lot. Thanks!